# Grant to Create User in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, role, sql-grant, createuser

I need create a user only to create others users, but, i don't know how create a grant to this?
Exist a method for this, or i need use `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the available permissions here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createuser.html

I believe the one you are looking for is `CREATEUSER`

The full command you'd want to execute is:

```
CREATE USER username WITH CREATEUSER;
```

Comment: I'd say this is correct. I'd also suggest that you might like to do something like this on the command line: `createuser -P -s -e <username>`. I personally find that way of doing it handier.

Comment: \h CREATE USER may also help ;)